# How can I calculate an entire family of smooths using geom_smooth() and display each one using facet_wrap()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm, smoothing, facet-wrap

In the documentation for [`geom_smooth()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html), there is an example that shows how to fit a B-spline smooth to the `hwy` vs. `displ` columns of the tidyverse [mpg dataset](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/mpg.html), using a parameter setting for the [`bs()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/splines/versions/3.6.2/topics/bs) function of `df=3`:

[image: geom_smooth() usage example]

I'd like to repeat the same example, but instead of computing just a single smooth with a single setting for the `df` parameter, I'd like to use a range of `df` values (for example, 3, 5, 7, 9) to calculate a series of smooths, and then display each smooth in a separate panel using `facet_wrap()` (and also as a minor addition, I furthermore want to display the gray-shaded confidence interval around the smooth curve).  However, I can't quite figure out what syntax I should use, or indeed whether ggplot2 even has the flexibility to support a computation such as this directly inside of `geom_smooth()`.

I've posted a MWE below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(splines)

# ---- Preface with optional additional problem context ----

# This fits 4 different B-splines to the "hwy" vs. "displ" columns of the 
# tidyverse "mpg" tibble, with the bs() df parameter set to c(3, 5, 7, 9).
# This is essentially representative of the kind of result I want, except
# that instead of computing it externally and saving the result to a list
# as I've done here, I want to do it automatically inside of geom_smooth().
fitobj <- list()
for(ii in seq(3,9,2)) {
  fitobj[[as.character(ii)]] <- lm(formula = hwy ~ bs(displ, df=ii), data=mpg)
}

# ---- MWE really starts here ----

# Make 4 identical copies of the "mpg" tibble, with an extra column tacked
# onto the right containing values 3, 5, 7, 9
mpg_rep <- NULL
for(ii in seq(3,9,2)) {
    tbl <- mpg
    tbl$splinedf <- ii
    mpg_rep <- bind_rows(mpg_rep, tbl)  
}

# Make a baseline plot; smooths will be appended afterward
plt <- ggplot(mpg_rep, aes(x=displ, y=hwy, group=splinedf)) +
       geom_point() +
       facet_wrap(~splinedf)

# This does _almost_ what I want, except that instead of plotting a different
# smooth in each panel, it plots the same smooth four times redundantly
print(plt + geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ bs(x, df=3)))

# This looks like it has sort of the right syntax to do what I want, however
# it returns an error message; I guess perhaps because I'm not allowed to
# reference an aesthetic like this inside a formula?
print(plt + geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ bs(x, df=splinedf)))
```

and this is an example output that looks *almost* like what I want, except that I want 4 different smooths instead of the same smooth 4 times:

[image: example output showing one smooth repeated 4 times instead of 4 unique smooths]

How can I revise the MWE to get it to do exactly what I want?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do what you want - I don't think `geom_smooth()` is quite that flexible. If you would be interested I could give an answer that constructs the data for the curves fairly efficiently with tidyverse tools and generates the plot. But if you're definitely *only* interested in a solution that works inside of `geom_smooth()`, I won't bother ...

Comment: @BenBolker: if your solution also includes an illustration of how to construct the confidence intervals and  display them in gray shading around the primary blue line (similar to the way `geom_smooth()` already does when computing the smooth internally) then yes I would be interested in that as a workaround solution.  But if it's just superimposing the fitted blue curve by itself (without confidence intervals) using an additional data frame or tibble, then I would say maybe don't bother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `lapply()` smooth layers to add to the plot, whilst simultaneously providing new facet variables.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  lapply(c(3,5,7,9), function(i) {
    geom_smooth(
      data = ~ cbind(., facet = i),
      method = lm,
      formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, i)
    )
  }) +
  facet_wrap(vars(facet))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Wow; very interesting technique.  Before now, I had never encountered a ggplot expression with an lapply() expression nested inside of it, and I was not aware that one could even do this.  I just learned some advanced R today; thank you for taking the time to respond.